# Find unique characters in the first string based on second string and out should be there is no duplicates in java

Tags: string

String str1 ="India is a great country";

String str2 = "Isgt";

**Output:** ndarecouy

Could you please help me anyone.

This is i tried

```
public static void main (String [] arg) {
    
    String str1 ="India is a great country";
    String str2 = "Isgt";
    // Expected output =  ndarecouy
    String result ="";
    for(int i =0 ; i <str2.length(); i++) {
        String value1 = String.valueOf(str2.charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j< str1.length() ; j++) {
            String value2 = String.valueOf(str1.charAt(i));
             if (value1.equalsIgnoreCase(value2)) {
                 
             } else {
                 result+= value2;
             }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("My program return this output: " +result);
            
}
```

**My program return this output:** nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnddddddddddddddddddddddddiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Comment: Please include your attempt and describe how it fails to meet the requirement. See [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Also, specify what language you are working in! If you haven't picked one yet, you'll need to think about that first yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop should be iterating through the characters of `str1` not `str2`. And in the inner loop you mistakenly use `i` rather than `j` as the index. However, even with those changes the algorithm would not be correct.

What you need to do is iterate through each character in `str1` and only add each character to `result` if it is not found in `str2` and not found in `result`. You could do this using inner loops, but using `indexOf` or `contains` would be simpler.

I have posted an example solution below, but I recommend you do not study it until you have spent several hours trying to solve the problem yourself.

```java
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    String str1 = "India is not a bad country";
    String str2 = "Isgt";
    String result = "";
    String str2Lower = str2.toLowerCase();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
        char value1 = Character.toLowerCase(str1.charAt(i));
        if (!Character.isSpaceChar(value1) 
                && str2Lower.indexOf(value1) == -1
                && result.indexOf(value1) == -1) {
            result += value1;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("My program return this output: " + result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. I understood now